# Does Cycle.js DOM driver works with JSX for transforms?

Tags: javascript, dom, jsx, cyclejs

I have a very simple transform on top of a DOM source on a cycles piece of code:

```
const tt_dom$ = tt_slider.DOM
   .map(vn => {vn.sel += '.tt';console.log(9870, vn); return vn})
```

Now if the component (i.e. `tt_slider`) specifies the HTML code without JSX, say

```
div('.myclass', [])
```

Then I get the desired output from my transform:

```
<div class="myclass tt">
```

But if I specify this using JSX:

```
 <div className="myclass">
```

I just get

```
<div class="myclass">
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this standard behavior? Or maybe a bug somewhere on Cycles?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `className` prop in Snabbdom overwrites all other css classes (in your case the `sel`). The reason why your hyperscript code works is that you dont use the `props` but the `sel` instead.

If you change it to `div({ props: { className: 'myClass' }}, [])` you will see the same issue.
I've openened a bug report for snabbdom, but it seems like this is indended behavior.

You could solve your issue by making the transform use the `className` prop.